# ServerControl randomly null

Tags: asp.net

I got a master page with a server control in it. Randomly the server control is inaccessible from codebehind. This doesn't happen on a specific action (eg a Button click or so). Currently I have no clue what this could be. I don't *think* it's output caching since this is not explcitly activated and the error happens far to seldom for that. But I'm going to disable caching in the master page explicitly with next deployment.

Anyone an idea how to find more info to find what's happening? Or has someone had a similar error?

The control is defined in markup. The accompaning codebehind is:

```
PGFMainNavi.HasAccessToFunction = HasAccessToNaviItem;
// HasAccessToNavi is a local function
```

Exception is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance 
of an object
```

Thanks.

sa

Comment: Is the control created dynamically in any way? Can you post your code so that we can see if anything there may be the cause?

Comment: You also need to place here what is the exception that you get.

Comment: @Robin Day: Defined in markup, @Aristos: Added to question

Comment: output caching is not related. I'm sure we'll be able to help you you you post more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar errors when I cache my controls - and I always check if their null, or if they are the correct types.

I think that your control is cached somewhere.

Use this code, to check that is not cached.

```
if(PGFMainNavi != null)
{
   PGFMainNavi.HasAccessToFunction = HasAccessToNaviItem;
}
```

or find where you set the case on this control and remove it.

### Second Solution

Some times after an online update I get this error, because compiler did fail to read correct all involving files - probably some user read the page the same time I copy the files or something.

To avoid that I always use the **app_offline.htm** before make my updates.

Comment: The != null solution worked out, though it *should* not have been cached. Bit puzzled, but I have talked to a colleague and he told me that the particular control act similar at his project.

Comment: probably your control fail to load for some reason... I make this checks for almost all my custom controls in my pages.